# How to print using scanf() function in C programming?

Tags: c

Is it any possible chance to print to IO device with the help of scanf() function?

```
main()
{
char str[30];
scanf("\n Name ?%s",&str);

printf("\n Name Entered is %s",str);
}
```

Try this and help me out.

Comment: How do you want to do output using an input function?

Comment: Yes. I came across that it is possibl.

Answer (score 6):

The `scanf` function reads input from the console and parses it. It has no means of printing anything. That's what the aptly-named `printf` family of functions is for.

Answer (score 4):

The first argument to `scanf` is not a prompt (as it looks like you're assuming), it's the format string to be used to scan the input.

That `scanf` will fail unless your input matches *exactly* what's expected including the literal string `"Name ?"` and so forth. It will also stop at the first whitespace so entering `udhayar kumar` would only get your first name. If you want a prompt simply output it beforehand such as with:

```
char str[30];
printf ("Name? ");
scanf ("%s", str);

printf ("Name Entered is %s\n", str);
```

However keep in mind that unbound `%s` format specifiers for `scanf` are an easy way to crash your program or give someone a security hole they can get through (see "buffer overflow"). That's because there's no bounds checking on the input.

If you want a decent input function, check out [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921). It gets an entire line (with optional prompt) and handles error conditions well.

Comment: scanf("\n Name ?%s",&str);
This actually works. Try to work with it. After running the file, type " Name ?udhay" and press enter. Now String "udhay" is assigned to var str. Check it out.... Thanx for ur respons too.

Comment: Yes, it works (for some definitions of 'work') but it constrains your input. What you see is _no_ indication that the program is waiting, and you have to enter not only your name but all that unnecessary cruft before it - that seems like a very badly designed way to get someone's name. In any case, that's _still_ not printing with `scanf` as your question asks.